# Evenly distribute lists into sublists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I want to evenly distribute a list into a given number of sublists.
For example, I have a list with elements 1 to 10 and I want 3 lists. These should look like:

```
SL1 -> {1, 2, 3, 4}
SL2 -> {5, 6, 7}
SL3 -> {8, 9, 10}
```

**Important**: What each list contains is not relevant, i.e. SL1 could have {1, 5, 7, 10}. The most important thing is that there are 2 lists with size 3 and 1 list with size 4.

I have tried several things, including the `Iterables.partition` but that won't help.

The only thing I've come up with that works is:

```
public Iterable<List<Integer>> distributeEvenlyQueryListIntoLists(final LinkedList<Integer> bigList, final Integer numberOfSublists) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // Creates as many lists as needed
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSublists; i++) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    while (bigList.iterator().hasNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSublists; i++) {
            if (!bigList.iterator().hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
            result.get(i).add(bigList.poll());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The passed `bigList` does not have to be a `LinkedList`, it can be any `Iterable`.

I especially hate the first loop where I create the sublists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just distribute them in a round-robin pattern:

```
public <T> List<List<T>> partition(Iterable<T> iterable, int partitions){
    List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>(partitions);
    for(int i = 0; i < partitions; i++)
        result.add(new ArrayList<>());

    Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator()
    for(int i = 0; iterator.hasNext(); i++)
        result.get(i % partitions).add(iterator.next());

    return result;
}
```

A sample run with this code:

```
List<String> l = Stream.iterate(0, i->i + 1).limit(25).map(i->Integer.toString(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(partition(l, 4).toString());
```

Produces

> [[0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24], [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21], [2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22], [3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23]]

The basic idea is to add a single element to each list in the result set roundwise. This way it's guaranteed that the difference in the number of elements between two lists never exceeds 1.

As an alternative you could use guavas implementation of [Iterables.partition](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#partition-java.lang.Iterable-int-), which takes a slightly different approach.

Comment: Great love this one, thanks! Any way I could rid of the first loop? It was actually what was bothering me the most from my original solution.

Comment: @user3083022 not really. You could use a bit of magic to make it look differently, but in the end you'll always wind up with creating all those list-instances.

Comment: What kind of magic you're talking about? Even if it's an external one-liner I'd take it

Comment: The first loop, where you create all the sublist objects, is effectively unavoidable. You could fold it into the latter loop, but you then end up with a conditional inside the latter loop (check if the sublist exists; if not create it) which would probably increase execution time, since that check would happen once for every element in the big list.

Comment: @user3083022 the magic could be something like `Stream.of(ArrayList::new, i->ArrayList::new).limit(partitions).collect(Collectors.toList())`, but that's really hackish. One alternate way that just came to my mind would be to restrict the input to type `List<T>` and use `subList`, which would create views of the original list.

Comment: I think I'm not getting that alternate way you mentioned. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @user3083022 Should actually be `Stream.iterate(new ArrayList<T>(), ArrayList::new).limit(partitions).collect(Collectors.toList())` (I've confused the method-calls). The basic idea is to create an endless stream of lists, limit that stream to the number of required lists and collect all lists in the stream into a single list. But I'd never the less advise you to **not** use this. It's just a bit of playing around with Java8, but way too hackish for actual code.

Comment: Mmh I'll benchmark both ways tomorrow and see which one performs better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you hate creating sublists, that implies you're looking for a fast solution. *If you have the original `List`, and you plan on not altering the original `List`*, consider `List.subList()`.

```
int subSize = bigList.length() / numSubs;
int numBigSubs = 0; // # of subs that need to be one bigger
if (bigList.length() % numSubs > 0) {
     subSize++;
     numBigSubs = bigList.length() % numSubs;
}
int from = 0;
int to  = subSize;
List<List<Integer>> subList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(numSubs);
for (int i = 0; i < numSubs; i++) {
    List<Integer> newSub = bigList.subList(from, to);
    subList.add (newSub);
    from = to;
    to += subSize;
    if (i >= numBigSubs && numBigSubs > 0) to--; 
}
```

*Note: I wrote this without testing - if it fails, I apologize, and hope someone will edit it to work.*

Again, the big upside to this is that it should be wicked fast - all the sublists are simply views into the larger one. The downside is that if you change the list, all bets are off.

Comment: This code doesn't do what it's supposed to. Assume `input-list % numSubs = 3`. Your code will produce `numSubs - 1` lists with `subSize` elements and one list with `subSize - 3` elements.

Comment: I was just editing the code to handle this, so it might address your concern. Now, if `big.length() == 15 && numSubs==4`, say, then `subSize` will now set to `big.length() / numSubs + 1 == 4`, and you should now get sublists going 0-4, 4-8, 8-12, 12-15, which should be correct. What do you think?

Comment: (The OP didn't completely specify, but I'm guessing round-robin is desired as you mentioned, i.e. all sublist lengths should be within 1 of each other, with the firstmost sublists being the larger ones, if necessary.)

Comment: Nope. The problem remains. You don't miss any elements due to a  too small `subSize`. The problem is that all lists in the partition except for the last will be of size `subSize`, which means that the last list in the partition will potentially miss a lot of elements. I just noticed my calculation is actually wrong.

Comment: I'm assuming you're actually running this code (I have no compiler here atm), so if it does what you say, I admit I'm stumped. The last sublist ought to be of elements 12-14 of a 15-element input list, which is exactly correct, yes?

Comment: It is correct in that specific case, yes. But this is only due to the fact that there is precisely one element missing to make all lists evenly partitioned. Consider how this code works for a list of length 18 and 5 partitions.

Comment: A simple way to fix this would be the following: considering `subList` as a matrix, you could transpose it, which would yield the desired property of having (almost aka off by at most 1 element) equally sized partitons. Downside would be the fact that number of partitions would be incorrect. And OP actually requires the input to be of type `Iterable`, which imposes the problem of first transforming from `Iterable` to `List` to your solution.

Comment: Aye, you're right - from my view, I was only considering cases where only the final sublist needed to be smaller. ...I would probably amend my code by tracking the lists that need to be one larger. Uno momento...

Comment: ...okay. This time, I added a count of "lists that must be bigger than the last lists", and `from` and `to` should be tracked accurately according to my notepad-debugging. Nice catch; I hope it's closer. Generally I'd only meant to advertise `subList()`; this is becoming non-trivial, but meh, fencepost errors are the bane of our existence...

Comment: Thanks @PaulBrinkley, I'll try your solution tomorrow. Looks a bit more verbose than Paul 's, but with a for loop less!

Comment: @PaulBrinkley works fine, apart from a few problems with the calculation of `numBigSubs`, but that's not too complicated to fix.

Comment: Harumph. One more fix, possibly addressing that `numBigSubs` problem. I hate fenceposts.

Comment: @PaulBrinkley you need to take a few things into consideration: your `for`-loop is 0-based, while ` numBigSubs` isn't. The condition actually updates the bounds for the **next** list, not the one that is currently created.

Comment: Well of course it is. And I normally set indices like `from` and `to` at the beginning of a loop, not the front, which is why that didn't occur to me until you mentioned it... okay, changed the conditional at the end. Things I'd find if only I had a compiler here...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#partition-java.util.List-int-) to create equal size sublists.

```java
List<String> bigList = ...
int batchSize = 1000;
List<List<String>> smallerLists = ListUtils.partition(bigList, batchSize);
```